# How to fix native android crash?

Tags: android, flutter

I am using flutter version 1.22.6. Crash happens only on android 11. Crashlytics does not show these crashes, only Google Console. Maybe the crash occurs at the start. I've downloaded debug symbols, but the backtrace doesn't show the exact location where the error happens.

Crash not reproduce on test devices on android 11.

=================================================================

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.colorfolio.color <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 0000000000089acc  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 00000000002bd2d0  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002b3f60  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002f2718  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002e68ac  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002e7060  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002e6c0c  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002ec7e4  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002be6ec  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002c08e0  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 0000000000019da8  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+916)
  #00  pc 00000000000199ac  /system/lib64/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+112)
  #00  pc 0000000000012c74  /system/lib64/libandroid.so (ALooper_pollOnce+100)
  #00  pc 00000000002c09f0  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002bda38  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000002bf75c  /data/app/~~wORiTEq_DBB7fcu-gwBIyg==/com.colorfolio.color-J9dU6UhDgJeqIBq4DC-knw==/split_config.arm64_v8a.apk!lib/arm64-v8a/libflutter.so (offset 0x8ba000)
  #00  pc 00000000000eb868  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 000000000008ba88  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```